# How can I check if a process is still running from the kernel in c?

Tags: linux, process, kernel, driver

All the answers I've seen so far appear to just be checking within user space. I need a way to check from kernel space specifically within a device driver. I get the task_struct associated with the process through an ioctl call from the process so I have all the information contained in that at my disposal.

Note: the process I'm looking for is running in user space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help:

```
struct task_struct { 
   volatile long state;    /* -1 unrunnable, 0 runnable, >0 stopped */
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm that definitely seems like it should do the trick but maybe my problems are caused by something else or maybe I just don't understand enough about the Linux kernel.  

If I stop the process while it is running with ctrl-c, would task->state return a value greater than 0?  

I'm sending signals with send_sig_info to the process from the kernel space. The process runs fine and gets the signals while running but as soon as a stop it, Linux crashes. I have `if(task->state == 0)` right before I send the signal.

Comment: @user1061166 if you hit ctrl-c the process should have ceased to exist.

Comment: @user1061166 I don't know, that's as far as my knowledge extends.  I would have presumed that the `task_struct` would have been invalidated at that point.  Maybe you need a lock around obtaining the pointer and testing it?

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I think a lock wouldn't work here because I get the pointer early on when the application first runs but don't check it until much later.

Comment: @user1061166 do you really need to get the `task_struct` that early, or could you get it again just before testing?

Comment: I was having issues getting it when I need to test it. It seemed like the pointer was always null when I used `task = find_task_by_pid(PID)`

Comment: @user1061166 maybe that's your problem? ;-)

Comment: Yeah I guess when I was doing that the originally I wasn't using rcu_read_[un]lock() when getting the task_struct pointer but started doing that when I moved where I got the pointer. Moving the code back to where I can check it lets me check for the pointer being NULL which has solved the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually it seems to be fine the first time this assignment occurs but is NULL every time after that. Oh well at least now I know what part of the code to focus on.